# Trying to add few conditions to exculde some results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add some conditions in mysql query but I am not sure why is it not working, here is the original code which I am trying to modify

```
public function getAffiliates($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) AS name, (SELECT SUM(at.amount) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate_transaction at WHERE at.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id GROUP BY at.affiliate_id) AS balance FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate a";

    $implode = array();

    if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
        $implode[] = "CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_email'])) {
        $implode[] = "LCASE(a.email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_email'])) . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_code'])) {
        $implode[] = "a.code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_code']) . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_status']) && !is_null($data['filter_status'])) {
        $implode[] = "a.status = '" . (int)$data['filter_status'] . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_approved']) && !is_null($data['filter_approved'])) {
        $implode[] = "a.approved = '" . (int)$data['filter_approved'] . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_added'])) {
        $implode[] = "DATE(a.date_added) = DATE('" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_added']) . "')";
    }

    if ($implode) {
        $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $implode);
    }

    $sort_data = array(
        'name',
        'a.email',
        'a.code',
        'a.status',
        'a.approved',
        'a.date_added'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY name";
    }

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC";
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

I am trying to modify the second line of the above code to not select any row containing "`Pending`" and "`Canceled`" in column name "`status`"

This is what I am trying to add

```
AND (status != 'Pending' AND status != 'Cancelled')
```

like this:

Replacing this code

```
$sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) AS name, (SELECT SUM(at.amount) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate_transaction at WHERE at.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id GROUP BY at.affiliate_id) AS balance FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate a";
```

with this

```
$sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) AS name, (SELECT SUM(at.amount) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate_transaction at WHERE at.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id AND (status != 'Pending' AND status != 'Cancelled') GROUP BY at.affiliate_id) AS balance FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "affiliate a";
```

I am still getting the all the results including the ones with `"Pending"` and `"Cancelled"` in `status` column, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: a status can't be both `"Pending" AND "Cancelled"`, so you need an `OR` - `AND (status != 'Pending' OR status != 'Cancelled')`. alternatively you could also do `AND status NOT IN ("Pending", "Cancelled")`

Comment: @Sean I tried with both methods but still not working

Comment: all your columns have a table alias, so `status` should probably be `a.status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my 10 years working with MySQL, I've never tried subqueries in the SELECT field list; perhaps you're running into a bug? Either way, this might be faster, as I would imagine that subquery is run separately for every row.

```
SELECT `a`.*
   , CONCAT(`a`.firstname, ' ', `a`.lastname) AS name
   , SUM(IFNULL(`at`.amount, 0)) AS balance
FROM affiliate AS `a`
   LEFT JOIN affiliate_transaction AS `at` 
   ON `a`.affiliate_id = `at`.affiliate_id
   AND `at`.status NOT IN ('Pending', 'Cancelled')
WHERE [affiliate conditions]
GROUP BY `a`.affliate_id
;
```

Depending on indexing/data, this might be even faster:

```
SELECT `a`.*
   , CONCAT(`a`.firstname, ' ', `a`.lastname) AS name
   , SUM(IF(`at`.status IS NULL OR `at`.status IN ('Pending', 'Cancelled')
            , 0, `at`.amount)
   ) AS balance
FROM affiliate AS `a`
   LEFT JOIN affiliate_transaction AS `at` 
   ON `a`.affiliate_id = `at`.affiliate_id
WHERE [affiliate conditions]
GROUP BY `a`.affliate_id
;
```

Edit: Oops, GROUP BY would help.

Comment: It's still not working, maybe it is because it is not custom code but a part of opencart?

Comment: @Muhammad, I am not sure it solves any issues you had with it, but I've edited the suggestions above.